# Assignment from incompatible pointer type in my Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, pointers, types, variable-assignment

Yesterday, I copied and compiled the code below and it was fine.  But today when I compiled the code it gave me a warning and won't run the `.exe`. I'm new in Objective-C and I'm using GNUstep on window.

```
testString.m: In function 'main':
testString.m:5:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
** testString.m:5:13 it front of (=)
```

Here's the code.

```
//testString.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main (int argc,  const char * argv[])
{
NSString *testString = [[NSString alloc] init ];
testString = "Here's a test string in testString!";
NSLog(@"testString: %@", testString);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

NSString literals must have @ symbol before them:

```
testString = @"Here's a test string in testString!";
```

One more problem with your code is that in 1st line you create an instance of NSString which you overwrite in the 2nd line - so it just leaks. Assign value to testString in its declaration directly:

```
NSString *testString = @"Here's a test string in testString!";
```